# Check Service Exists using regular expression

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I had a service. I want to know whether the service had been installed on the system or not. I can provide some part of the service name but not entirely.
I have tried couple of commands but couldn't get the result.

```
 sc query
 find
```

But the above command lists only active services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 sc query | findstr /r /i "time"&&echo found||echo not found
```

You need to think about your search string. Running above command will show you why.

Comment: The command only gets those services which are active and running.

Comment: I was using your command. If you want it to do all then tell it to. Don't whinge at me. You indicated you only wanted active services. OR DID YOU POST CODE FOR NO REASON. `sc query type= all`

Comment: I didn't mention anywhere in my question that I need only active services. I am glad you answered but that doesn't serve my purpose. That was my intention.

Comment: Look what you wrote `sc query` I answered about your ignorance about command line syntax.